# How to get data from sheet one and paste the values underneath a dataset

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Im trying to copy values from 'Source' and set them in the lowest blank row in 'Dataset'.
The issue is that the script is literally copying everything, while it should only set the Values without format or formula.

The code I am using is

```
function copyInfo() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var copySheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById('Sheet1').getSheetByName('Dashboard');
  var pasteSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById('Sheet1').getSheetByName('Dataset');

  // get source range
  var source = copySheet.getRange(7,2,32,11);
  // get destination range
  var destination = pasteSheet.getRange(pasteSheet.getLastRow()+1,1,1,11);

  // copy values to destination range
  source.copyTo(destination);

}
```

The issue is that the script is literally copying everything, while it should only set the Values without format or formula.

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
  // copy values to destination range
  source.copyTo(destination);
```

To

```
  // copy values to destination range
  source.copyTo(destination, {contentsOnly:true});
```

Reference

- [Range.copyTo()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#copyTo(Range,Object))